# Ninja forms - Using custom action, how can I handle the form's status based on the api's response?

Tags: wordpress, oauth, ninja-forms

Using a custom action, I post the submissions of a form to an third-party API route. This part works well, i.e. the data is received and properly processed by  the api (I've created a custom plugin to handle all of the api's requests).

Basically, on submit, the custom action is triggered and its callback fires the api request. What I can't figure out is how to display on the front-end if the api call succeeded, and, if not, the correct error message.

Here's the code I use thus far (it's WIP, but do not hesitate to point if I'm doing something wrong) :

The custom hook :

```php
<?php 
add_action('bo_api_form_processing', 'bo_api_custom_form_process');

function bo_api_custom_form_process($form_data) {

  $client = new ApiClient;

  $submit = $client->sendNewBeneficiaire($form_data);
}
```

the api client :

```php
final class ApiClient {
      public function sendNewBeneficiaire($form_data) {
    $token = $this->authenticate();

    $url = self::API_URL . '/beneficiaire';

    $fields = $this->filterFields($form_data['fields']);


    if (empty($fields['session']) ||
      empty($fields['nom'])   ||
      empty($fields['prenom'])  ||
      empty($fields['pays'])    ||
      empty($fields['email'])) {
      echo wp_json_encode('Des informations sont manquantes ou erronnées dans votre préinscription. Merci de réessayer ultérieurement');
    }

    // TODO remove when done testing
    $fields['session'] = '14';

    $data = [
      'groupeid' => $fields['session'],
      'lastname' => $fields['nom'],
      'firstname' => $fields['prenom'],
      'address' => $fields['adresse'],
      'codepostal' => $fields['code-postal'],
      'city' => $fields['ville'],
      'country' => $fields['pays'],
      'numadelie' => $fields['numero-adeli'],
      'siret' => $fields['numero-siret'],
      'phone' => $fields['telephone'],
      'email' => $fields['email'],
      'job' => $fields['job']
    ];

    $args = [
      'method' => 'POST',
      'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      ],
      'body' => $data,
    ];

    try {
      $query = wp_remote_post($url, $args);

      if ($query instanceof WP_Error) {
        echo wp_json_encode($query->get_error_message());
      }
      else {
        echo wp_json_encode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($query));
      }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      //
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I've been scratching my head on that one for days, and I'm pretty sure it is something simple but ... well, I would really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

sendNewBeneficiaire() in ApiClient seems to echo the result out instead of returning it, so you have two options:

1. Modify sendNewBeneficiaire() method in your API and instead of `echo` use `return` or;
2. In bo_api_custom_form_process() function wrap API call in ob_start()/ob_get_clean() to get output buffer into variable.

E.g.

```
add_action('bo_api_form_processing', 'bo_api_custom_form_process');
function bo_api_custom_form_process($form_data) {
    $client = new ApiClient;
    ob_start();
    $submit = $client->sendNewBeneficiaire($form_data);
    $result = ob_get_clean();

    // your API output is now stored in variable $result.
}
```

PS: It doesn't look like you are registering Ninja Forms action properly. Here is what it typically looks like:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_register_actions', 'register_actions' );
function register_actions( $actions ) {
    $actions['your_action_name'] = new YourActionClass();
    return $actions;
}

class YourActionClass extends NF_Abstracts_Action {
    protected $_name = 'your_action_name';
    protected $_timing = 'late'; // for API calls
    protected $_priority = '100';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_nicename = esc_html__( 'Action Name', 'text-domain' );
    }

    public function save( $action_settings ){}

    public function process( $action_settings, $form_id, $data ) {
        // do api request

        return $data;
    }
}
```